# Migrating TomEE 7.1.2 to 9.1.2 throws javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name "nullDatabasePropertiesServiceImplLocal" not found

Tags: ejb, apache-tomee

I'm migrating from tomEE 7.1.2 to tomEE 9.1.2 but while starting the tomEE server I'm seeing lot of exceptions like,

```
07-Mar-2024 18:27:23.832 SEVERE [main] org.apache.openejb.core.singleton.SingletonInstanceManager.createInstance The bean instance accessnirvana-xanadu/DetectInactivePasswordFilterPoller threw a system exception:org.apache.openejb.InvalidateReferenceException: java.rmi.RemoteException: The bean encountered a non-application exception; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while initializing context: The bean encountered a non-application exception; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while initializing context
    org.apache.openejb.InvalidateReferenceException: java.rmi.RemoteException: The bean encountered a non-application exception; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while initializing context: The bean encountered a non-application exception; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while initializing context
        at org.apache.openejb.core.transaction.EjbTransactionUtil.handleSystemException(EjbTransactionUtil.java:156)
        at org.apache.openejb.BeanContext.newInstance(BeanContext.java:1795)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.singleton.SingletonInstanceManager.createInstance(SingletonInstanceManager.java:179)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.singleton.SingletonInstanceManager$1.call(SingletonInstanceManager.java:120)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.singleton.SingletonInstanceManager$1.call(SingletonInstanceManager.java:118)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.singleton.SingletonInstanceManager.getInstance(SingletonInstanceManager.java:129)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.singleton.SingletonInstanceManager.initialize(SingletonInstanceManager.java:93)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.singleton.SingletonInstanceManager.start(SingletonInstanceManager.java:84)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.singleton.SingletonContainer.start(SingletonContainer.java:127)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs(Assembler.java:1697)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:1008)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:762)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1340)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1162)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:134)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5085)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1188)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:2023)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1098)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:480)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1708)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:320)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:946)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:886)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:265)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:795)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
    Caused by: java.rmi.RemoteException: The bean encountered a non-application exception; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while initializing context
        at org.apache.openejb.core.transaction.EjbTransactionUtil.handleSystemException(EjbTransactionUtil.java:155)
        ... 56 more
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while initializing context
        at com.tuebora.services.common.AbstractServiceFactory.getDatabasePropertyService(AbstractServiceFactory.java:539)
        at com.tuebora.services.pwdmanagement.DetectInactivePasswordFilterPoller.startEventPoller(DetectInactivePasswordFilterPoller.java:41)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:211)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$LifecycleInvocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:265)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:192)
        at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.record(StatsInterceptor.java:191)
        at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.PostConstruct(StatsInterceptor.java:119)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:211)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:192)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.InterceptorStack.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:95)
        at org.apache.openejb.BeanContext.newInstance(BeanContext.java:1792)
        ... 55 more
    Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name "nullDatabasePropertiesServiceImplLocal" not found.
        at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.naming.IvmContext.federate(IvmContext.java:211)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.naming.IvmContext.lookup(IvmContext.java:159)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.naming.ContextWrapper.lookup(ContextWrapper.java:137)
        at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:409)
        at com.tuebora.services.common.AbstractServiceFactory.getDatabasePropertyService(AbstractServiceFactory.java:536)
        ... 73 more
07-Mar-2024 18:27:23.832 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.destroyApplication Undeploying app: C:\repos\apache-tomee-server\webapps\accessnirvana-xanadu
07-Mar-2024 18:27:23.906 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.core.mdb.MdbContainer.undeploy Undeployed MDB control for accessnirvana-xanadu/ITSMTaskCompletedEventHandler
07-Mar-2024 18:27:23.906 INFO [main] org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQEndpointWorker.stop Stopping
07-Mar-2024 18:27:23.920 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.core.mdb.MdbContainer.undeploy Undeployed MDB control for accessnirvana-xanadu/RegistrationsQListener
07-Mar-2024 18:27:23.920 INFO [main] org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQEndpointWorker.stop Stopping
07-Mar-2024 18:27:23.954 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.core.mdb.MdbContainer.undeploy Undeployed MDB control for accessnirvana-xanadu/RequestApprovedEventHandler
07-Mar-2024 18:27:23.954 INFO [main] org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQEndpointWorker.stop Stopping
07-Mar-2024 18:27:23.954 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.core.mdb.MdbContainer.undeploy Undeployed MDB control for accessnirvana-xanadu/ProcessTriggerListener
07-Mar-2024 18:27:23.954 INFO [main] org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQEndpointWorker.stop Stopping
07-Mar-2024 18:27:23.967 INFO [main] org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector.stop Connector vm://localhost stopped
07-Mar-2024 18:27:24.033 SEVERE [main] jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Error destroying child
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted ([before_destroy]) for component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/accessnirvana-xanadu]] in state [STARTING_PREP]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.invalidTransition(LifecycleBase.java:430)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:316)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:826)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1688)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1668)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeployWebApps(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:801)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.destroyApplication(Assembler.java:2425)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:1103)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:762)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1340)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1162)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:134)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5085)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1188)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:2023)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1098)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:480)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1708)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:320)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:946)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:886)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:265)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:795)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
07-Mar-2024 18:27:24.983 SEVERE [main] org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal Unable to deploy collapsed ear in war StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/accessnirvana-xanadu]
    org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Creating application failed: C:\repos\apache-tomee-server\webapps\accessnirvana-xanadu: Error starting 'DetectInactivePasswordFilterPoller'.  Exception: class org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Singleton startup failed: accessnirvana-xanadu/DetectInactivePasswordFilterPoller: jakarta.ejb.NoSuchEJBException: Singleton failed to initialize: Singleton failed to initialize: Singleton startup failed: accessnirvana-xanadu/DetectInactivePasswordFilterPoller: jakarta.ejb.NoSuchEJBException: Singleton failed to initialize: Singleton failed to initialize
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:1107)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:762)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1340)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1162)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:134)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5085)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1188)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:2023)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1098)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:480)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1708)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:320)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:946)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:886)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:265)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:795)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
    Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Error starting 'DetectInactivePasswordFilterPoller'.  Exception: class org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Singleton startup failed: accessnirvana-xanadu/DetectInactivePasswordFilterPoller: jakarta.ejb.NoSuchEJBException: Singleton failed to initialize: Singleton failed to initialize: Singleton startup failed: accessnirvana-xanadu/DetectInactivePasswordFilterPoller: jakarta.ejb.NoSuchEJBException: Singleton failed to initialize: Singleton failed to initialize
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs(Assembler.java:1703)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:1008)
        ... 45 more
    Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Singleton startup failed: accessnirvana-xanadu/DetectInactivePasswordFilterPoller: jakarta.ejb.NoSuchEJBException: Singleton failed to initialize: Singleton failed to initialize
        at org.apache.openejb.core.singleton.SingletonInstanceManager.initialize(SingletonInstanceManager.java:98)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.singleton.SingletonInstanceManager.start(SingletonInstanceManager.java:84)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.singleton.SingletonContainer.start(SingletonContainer.java:127)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs(Assembler.java:1697)
        ... 46 more
    Caused by: org.apache.openejb.ApplicationException: jakarta.ejb.NoSuchEJBException: Singleton failed to initialize: Singleton failed to initialize
        at org.apache.openejb.core.singleton.SingletonInstanceManager.createInstance(SingletonInstanceManager.java:210)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.singleton.SingletonInstanceManager$1.call(SingletonInstanceManager.java:120)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.singleton.SingletonInstanceManager$1.call(SingletonInstanceManager.java:118)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.singleton.SingletonInstanceManager.getInstance(SingletonInstanceManager.java:129)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.singleton.SingletonInstanceManager.initialize(SingletonInstanceManager.java:93)
        ... 49 more
    Caused by: jakarta.ejb.NoSuchEJBException: Singleton failed to initialize
        ... 55 more
    Caused by: org.apache.openejb.InvalidateReferenceException: java.rmi.RemoteException: The bean encountered a non-application exception; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while initializing context: The bean encountered a non-application exception; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while initializing context
        at org.apache.openejb.core.transaction.EjbTransactionUtil.handleSystemException(EjbTransactionUtil.java:156)
        at org.apache.openejb.BeanContext.newInstance(BeanContext.java:1795)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.singleton.SingletonInstanceManager.createInstance(SingletonInstanceManager.java:179)
        ... 54 more
    Caused by: java.rmi.RemoteException: The bean encountered a non-application exception; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while initializing context
        at org.apache.openejb.core.transaction.EjbTransactionUtil.handleSystemException(EjbTransactionUtil.java:155)
        ... 56 more
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while initializing context
        at com.tuebora.services.common.AbstractServiceFactory.getDatabasePropertyService(AbstractServiceFactory.java:539)
        at com.tuebora.services.pwdmanagement.DetectInactivePasswordFilterPoller.startEventPoller(DetectInactivePasswordFilterPoller.java:41)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:211)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$LifecycleInvocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:265)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:192)
        at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.record(StatsInterceptor.java:191)
        at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.PostConstruct(StatsInterceptor.java:119)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:211)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:192)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.InterceptorStack.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:95)
        at org.apache.openejb.BeanContext.newInstance(BeanContext.java:1792)
        ... 55 more
    Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name "nullDatabasePropertiesServiceImplLocal" not found.
        at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.naming.IvmContext.federate(IvmContext.java:211)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.naming.IvmContext.lookup(IvmContext.java:159)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.naming.ContextWrapper.lookup(ContextWrapper.java:137)
        at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:409)
        at com.tuebora.services.common.AbstractServiceFactory.getDatabasePropertyService(AbstractServiceFactory.java:536)
        ... 73 more
```

I'm not sure what exactly is causing the problem.
First I thought it is related to only one specific class, So I commented the code and tried starting the server but found the same issue with the other class and so on.
There is a pattern, the classes which uses ejb I'm seeing issues in those classes.